# Distribution for random harmonic series

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider random variable $X$ formed by the following infinite series: $X = \pm 1 \pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{3} \pm ... \frac{1}{n} ...$, where $+$ or $-$ sign for every summand is chosen independently w.p. $1/2$. What is the distribution of $X$? If it is not some well-known distribution, does it have any interesting properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There might be no better answer than to direct you to [this paper](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/rhs.pdf) (which happens to be written by a contributor to this site): *Random harmonic series*, American Mathematical Monthly 110, 407-416, 2003.

Comment: very nice paper!